# SVN commit permission denied

Tags: linux, apache, svn

I get this annoying error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E204900: Can't open file '/var/www/repoFolder/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

I tried quite alot of things. There is no user apache, but there is one called www-data.

I gave www-data all rights, chmod 777, made it owner chown -R
It didn't work.

```
sudo gpasswd -a koskamp www-data
sudo chgrp -R www-data svn/
sudo chmod -R g=rwsx svn/
```

koskamp is here the user which I try to login with on the repo.

SELinux is not installed, or at least, it says that i should install it first when i try the following: getsebool -a | grep httpd

Quite a damn lot questions about this issue, but they don't help me out unfortunatly.

Comment: Undo the 777 and all other global write permission. It's an irresponsible way to attempt to "fix" a security problem, and just creates more. The owner of the repository directory needs to be the user account under which *Apache runs*, not the Subversion account that's performing the commit. Also, your repository should be *outside* the Apache docroot and reference from the appropriate `<Location>` block in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Oh my what, stupid thing. Well, you got it fixed there, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alroc made the answer!
Undo the 777 and all other global write permission. It's an irresponsible way to attempt to "fix" a security problem, and just creates more. The owner of the repository directory needs to be the user account under which Apache runs, not the Subversion account that's performing the commit. Also, your repository should be outside the Apache docroot and reference from the appropriate  block in httpd.conf. –  alroc Oct 10 '13 at 12:32